# $\left(a_n >0\to a>0\right)\implies\left(\sqrt{a_n}\to\sqrt{a}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ : $a_n > 0$ tends to $a>0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, then $\sqrt{a_n} \rightarrow \sqrt{a}$.

By the definition of a converging sequence, we have that $\forall \epsilon>0$ : $$(1):\vert a_n - a \vert< \epsilon$$

for some $N<n$. Since $a_n -a$ is positive, we can drop the absolute value sign $$a_n - a < \epsilon $$ $$a_n < \epsilon +a$$

Taking the square root of both sides preserves the direction $$\sqrt{a_n}<\sqrt{\epsilon + a}$$ $$\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{a} < \sqrt{\epsilon + a}-\sqrt{a}$$

Again the difference is positive so $$\vert\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{a}\vert < \sqrt{\epsilon + a}-\sqrt{a}$$

So now we have to choose an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ in equation $(1)$, so that our final result is instead
 $$\vert\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{a}\vert < \epsilon$$

Is the proof ok up to his point?

Comment: "By the definition of a converging sequence" ... this is wrong.  Look it up.  Get your quantifiers right.  "Since $a_n - a$ is positive" ... this is wrong.

Comment: No. You do not know that $a_n-a$ is positive. It might be negative.

Comment: You don't need $a>0;$ $a\ge 0$ is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A far easier method: multiply (and divide) by the conjugate.

$|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{a}|\frac{|\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{a}|}{|\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{a}|}=\frac{|a_n-a|}{|\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{a}|}<\frac{|a_n-a|}{\sqrt{a}}$.

Since $a_n \to a$, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have 
$$
|a_n-a|<\epsilon\sqrt{a}.
$$